# function to create a vectorized piecwise function R

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm pretty new to R so apologies in advance if this question is poorly constructed. Basically I have a piece-wise function that I need to calculate the value for a large number of rows. My current function looks something like this:

```
f <- function(x){
  (x <= 1000) * x^2 + 
  (x > 1000 & x <= 2000) * x^3 +
  (x > 2000 & x <= 3000) * x^4 +
  (x > 4000) * x^5 
  }
```

However I need to be able to create or generalize this function for a variety of different sets of breakpoints (ie maybe 1500,2500,3500, etc) and for different numbers of breakpoints. Also given the large number of rows that will need to be calculated on, the function has to be vectorized. Any advice?

Edit:

To clarify, I made the function  above from some table of breakpoints (1000,2000,3000,4000) and associated powers to raise x to (2,3,4,5). However I need to be able to take multiple of such tables, each with varying breakpoints and number of breakpoints (with potentially 100 or so breakpoints) and be able to apply the resulting piecewise function to a large number of rows.

Comment: vectorised over what? `x`? It already is.

Comment: See the edit I made. I realize that function is vectorized, but how can I reproduce it for lots of different piecewise functions with varying break points and varying number of break points.   @Chi Pak How can this help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vectorised version of your function with additional breaks and power arguments can be written this way:

```
function(x, breaks, power){
 x^power[as.numeric(cut(x, breaks))]
}
```

`as.numeric(cut(...))` gets the position of all `x` values in the breaks, then the square bracket looks up the power in the power vector and raises the corresponding x to the correct power. Tests:

Some breaks points and powers:

```
> bp <- c(10,20,30,40)
> po = c(2,3,4)
```

Note the breakpoints are left-excluded:

```
> f(9,bp,po)
[1] NA
> f(10,bp,po)
[1] NA
```

So the first valid `x` has to be above 10:

```
> f(11,bp,po)
[1] 121
```

And gets us 11^2 as expected. So 20 gets squared and 21 gets cubed:

```
> f(20,bp,po)
[1] 400

> f(21,bp,po)
[1] 9261
```

Good so far. Vectorised?

```
> f(19:22, bp, po)
[1]   361   400  9261 10648
```

Yes - the change from square to cube happens between 20 and 21.

See the help for the `right` option for the `cut` function if you want the intervals to be closed on the left or right.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your example code, you basically want to minimize the coding, and also want the code to be dynamic, so that you can dynamically vary the breaks and power.

Below is the sample code, which tries to do the same.

```
f <- function(x, breakPoints, powerX) {
  cutX <- cut(x, breaks=breakPoints)
  cutX1 <- factor(cutX, labels=powerX)
  retX <- x ^ as.numeric(as.character(cutX1))
  retX
}

x1 <- sample(1:10000, 1000)
x1 <- x1[order(x1)]
breakPoints1 <- c(min(x1)-1, 1000, 2000, 3000, max(x1))
powerX1 <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
newX1 <- f(x1, breakPoints1,  powerX1)

head(newX1) # manual check whether the values make sense
head(x1)
```

This code will do that.

But my suggestion will be to test this code, as much as possible, so that you can use it reliably. Hope this  code is useful to you.

Comment: This function fails in some cases, I think its if there's any interval with no points in it - then you get a cut vector that has fewer levels than expected, and a "invalid 'labels'; length 4 should be 1 or 3" error, but I've not looked too deep into it yet.